# How To get the Json array from API resource and bind it in the blade file using Jquery ajax in laravel?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I am new to laravel and jquery .

I have fetched the data from API Resource , it returned a **JSON response**.

I want the data to be binded to the blade file via jquery ajax..

Here is my code from scratch.

1.I have created a table named **Progress** with 5 fields

```
id
name
description
goal
value
```

2.Model : **App\Progress.php**

```
class Progress extends Model
{
     protected $table = 'progress';
     protected $fillable = [
        'id', 'name', 'goal', 'description', 'value'
    ];
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

3. Controller : **app/Http/Controllers/api/ProgressController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;
use App\Progress;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Resources\ProgressResource;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProgressController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
      return ProgressResource::collection(Progress::paginate(4));
      
}
}
```

4.Resources : **app/http/Resources/ProgressResource.php**

```
public function toArray($request)
    {
        return[
         'id' => $this->id,
         'name' => $this->name,
         'goal' => $this->goal,
         'description' => $this->description,
         'value' => $this->value,
  ];
    }
```

5.Blade file : **Welcome.blade.php**

```
@foreach($progress as $progressdata)
        <div class="col-md-4">
             <div class = "progress">
                 <div id = "goal"> {{ $progressdata->goal }} </div>
                 <div id = "value"> {{ $progressdata->value}} </div>
              </div>
         </div>
    </div>
 @endforeach
```

6.JS file: **main.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $.ajaxSetup({

        headers: {

            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }

    });
       var progress = [];
      $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "/api/progress",
          data: {progress:progress},
          success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
           }
        });
});
```

7.Routes file: **web.php**

```
Route::view('/', 'welcome');
```

I got this error

```
GET http://sampleprogresswidget.test/ 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

How to bind the dataarray from the resource collection in the blade file through jquery ajax .Could someone please help?

Comment: 500 means there is a problem with your code or server configuration. Please share the error you see when you make the request. Check **Network** on the console bar.

Comment: Request URL: http://sampleprogresswidget.test/
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 500 Internal Server Error . This is the error

Answer (score 0):

you should return json response like this

```
return response()->json([
'name' => 'Abigail',
'state' => 'CA',
 ]);
```

Comment: .Where should I implement this code .. I want  to get the entire Progress[] from api resource and to pass the array fields like goal and value to the blade file..

Comment: I implemented  $progress = ProgressResource::collection(Progress::paginate(4));
      return Response::json($progress); in my controller ..Got Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException error  Possible typo $progress..Could you please help?